# Is there any action filter in Rails for handling exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, ruby-on-rails-3

I was working on asp.net mvc before, now i am working on Ruby on Rails.

in asp.net mvc we use to handle validation using action filters, i am wondering if same thing is available in rails too.

i want to create custom validation class to handle business  validation, so that action filter can process the exception based on the type of exception it is.

Comment: i got the answers, we can do it using rescue_from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with asp.net, and may be misunderstanding your question but here is a way to handle exceptions that might occur when in an action of a Controller.

A generic Controller with some actions:

```
class SomethingController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

Notice that the SomethingController is inheriting from this ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    return render :json => {:status => 'error', :message => "given id does 
      not correlate to a record", :code => 404}
  end
end
```

Because the `SomethingController` (along with most other controllers) inherit from  `ApplicationController` most exception handlers can be placed in `ApplicationController`.

Now the actual exception is not generated in the controller, but rather comes from a model. In the example above, and assuming I only have 10 users, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` is an exception that will be called when the `User` model calls the `find_by_id` method with parameter 1000. There is no user with id 1000, so an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception will be returned to the calling controller. `SomethingController` doesn't know how to handle this action, and will thus refer to its parent which has an appropriate handler.